# Unsupported characters in parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json, ascii, utf

I am trying to parse the following string of JSON but it is throwing error because of the Up-Tack(Up-T) character. I tested that it works by removing the above mentioned character.

[image]

How do I obtain a list of all such characters in order to avoid code failures in future?

var someArray=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// where data contains the text.

ERROR:- SyntaxError: Invalid character\n   at parseJSON

NOTE:- There isn't a problem with the format of JSON. I may not be able to post the exact JSON here

Comment: Please show the exact JSON, the code you use to parse it and the exact error message.

Comment: *"I may not be able to post the exact JSON here"* An excerpt would suffice. For example, `["the offending string here"]` at that point your question would contain an MCVE (assuming it still failed, but if it didn't, that would make this question extremely unclear.)

Comment: It's guaranteed an issue with the JSON. Can you duplicate the error using non-sensitive JSON data?

Comment: I'm not seeing the same error as you are. Could you provide a sample of the JSON string you are typing to parse? This worked fine for me: `var json = '{"key":"value with ⊥ in it"}';    JSON.parse(json);`.

Comment: Any valid string is a valid key as long as you escape it: